# How to find trajectory path if the distance traveled, starting elevation, ending elevation and time in the air are known

Tags: math, physics

I'm trying to find the trajectory an object would take (assuming air drag is negligible and trajectory angle is always between 0 and 90), including peak height.  Here's what I know:

- takeoff point latitude, longitude, elevation
- landing poing latitude, longitude, elevation
- distance traveled
- amount of time in the air

For me the problem could be reduced to 2d space, so if an object travels a horizontal distance of 8 meters starting at an elevation of 0 and ending at a relative elevation of -5 meters, and travels for 2 seconds.  What was the peak height, and at what point in time did it reach that peak hight.

Also, trying to write this equation in to php, C, or objective C.  Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.

Comment: you did not specify what is the distance (perpendicular, curvature,???) also wrong tags cause your question is not seen by the right people. Is this assigment/homework? that should be specified too. **There is just one equation really: `pos''=vel'=acc`** where `'` means derivation by time. btw what have you tried ?

Comment: @Spektre thanks for your thoughts on this.  This is not an assignment/homework.  I've got GPS elevation data at 50hz to compare this trajectory path to, and I know it has some error to it so I was trying to figure out how to estimate the amount of error, and without the limitation of 50hz resolution.  What I had tried is to use other kinematic equations I had found, but they wanted to use trajectory angle (which I was also having trouble figuring out).

Comment: 1. so is your object cannonball like or not? (if it has own actuators like plane or rocket or have wings then the equation will change so specify this!)   2. At least in my language kinematics therm is used for something else try to look for dynamics or Newtonian and or D'Lambert principle/equations. 3. if the object also rotates it also can change the trajectory (depends on mass and rotation inertia, rotations axises and rpm ... this can lead to spiral like trajectory for some objects even on small rpm's !!!) 4. dynamic wings/shapes are a chapter of its own ...

Comment: btw you can approximate your data by polynomial function `y=a0+a1*t+a2*t*t+a3*t*t*t // y[m] t[s]` and compare `a0?=vy0` , `a1?=y0` , `a2?=-0.5*9.81` and `a3?=0.0` to check if this is your case

Comment: Definitely cannonball like trajectory with none of it's own actuators and no rotation.  You have an impressive grasp on this topic.  I will get back to where I can try this out in code soon.  Thanks

Comment: @user3167451 well I have years of experience in this but still I am no Guru (very far from it)... You will be amazed how much the real world around you is different from what you have learn at school. This will work at rough scales (or if no wibrations and other stuff is added) when you want to add precision and coherence with real measured data you will see a whole new world not unlike the quantum theory even on 0.001 mm scales. When I first came in contact with this I was stunned (I did not suspect/comprehend this can be the thing on scales so far from Planck's constant)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume cannon ball like trajectory

- object has some start velocity
- not slowing by air (specified by question)
- only gravity force apply

So

1. solve the equations to find missing data

   [image: cannon ball]

   ```
   g=9.81; // [m/s^2]
   t=!; // [s] time in air
   p0(x0,y0)=!; // [m] start point
   p1(x1,y1)=!; // [m] end point
   v0(vx0,vy0)=?; // [m/s] start velocity vector

   // Y axis free fall with initial velocity
   y1=y0+vy0*t-0.5*g*t*t
   vy0=(y1-y0+0.5*g*t*t)/t
   vy0=(y1-y0)/t+0.5*g*t

   // X axis constant speed
   vx0=(x1-x0)/t
   ```
2. trajectory path point

   ```
   x=x0+vx0*t;
   y=y0+vy0*t-0.5*g*t*t;
   ```

   where `t = <0.0,time_in_air>` so for plotting do some `for` loop through `t`
3. peak point:

   ```
   vy(t)=vy0-g*t;
   // for peak the y velocity is zero so
   0.0=vy0-g*t;
   t=vy0/g;
   ```

   where `t` is the time when object reach peak point. If you need coordinates then compute them like in bullet **#2**

Comment: Here's php code that should pretty closely match your pseudocode, and that is confirmed to be working very well for me.  Thanks!


`$yVelocity = (($end_elevation - $start_elevation) + ((0.5*32.174)*(pow($time_in_air,2))))/$time_in_air;
$time_in_air_at_apex = $yVelocity/32.174;`

Then to get height for any point during that trajectory you do this:

`$height = (($yVelocity * $sec) - ((0.5*32.174)*(pow($sec,2))));`