# Calculate velocity for vertical shoot

Tags: math, language-agnostic, physics, game-physics

I have the following code

```
const gravity = 3

y += (gravity / 2 + velocity);
velocity += gravity;
```

This calculates the free fall of an object affected by gravity. If I change velocity to a negative value, `velocity = -100` the object is thrown up, and smoothly begins to fall after a while.

I can do that, and it works well. But I need to calculate the **velocity** required for Y to reach certain target, at that point velocity will be 0. I don't want to manually change the velocity, but I want to change the target; velocity should be computed. For example, a function that I should call.

```
function hitTarget(y) {
    velocity = /* some math here */
}
// this would set velocity to -50 (in an example) after some calculations I can't figure out
hitTarget(10);
```

And then the Y values would be (for example):

```
100 // velocity starts at -50
50
35
22
17
12
10 // reached target! begins to descend. at this point velocity is 0.
12
17
22
35
50
100 // velocity is 50 and keeps increasing....
...
```

I have successfully done this using [Projectile Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion) formula:

```
y = velocity_y * time - (gravity * time * time) / 2;
```

But I can't set an absolute Y, as velocity can be changed any time by an external factor (input in this case). Besides, as the current formula is a little different, I get different movement.

**Remarks**

- Only Y axis, no horizontal movement needed
- -Y is up, +Y is down.

Comment: In that example, shouldn't it be `100, 51.5, 6, ...`?

Comment: So this is projectiles @ 90 deg only?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes, only in the Y axis, no horizontal movement needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the part where you mention the absolute Y. So do you start at a velocity necessary to hit a target Y, but then that velocity will change creating another Y?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes that's correct. velocity is updated every frame, but currently I can change it whenever I want (based on input at the moment). Like [Euler Integration](http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/14/understanding-motion-in-games), where `pos = pos + vel` and `vel = vel + acel`

Comment: It sounds like you know the answer but maybe haven't made the equation; that or I'm still lost. `velocity = y/t - gt/2`; assuming you starting position is 0. Is that helping at all or am I pointing out the obvious? --Initial velocity to reach `y` that is.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, Thanks for your help! What should `t` be? Remember I don't track the time.

Comment: What do you mean, you can change the velocity whenever you want? Is that the same "you" that wants the object to reach the target with velocity=0?

Comment: @Beta, yes, I clarified a little bit because I thought it was confusing. Currently I **can** set the velocity to whatever and whenever I want, and it works fine. But I don't need that, I want instead to set a target Y. Velocity should be computed. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: Well, I about made a conundrum. You can use `-v1 = sqrt(2gy - (v2)^2)`. This way you can avoid negative roots and handle it on the other side.

Comment: What about the values in your example? It starts at (y=100,v=-50), then `y += (gravity / 2 + velocity);`, so y=100 + 3/2 -50 = 51.5, isn't that right?

Comment: @Beta yep you are right! I made a mistake in the example.

Comment: There is a basic problem here. You can bring the object to the target altitude with vel=0, but in most cases that will not occur at one of the discrete time steps. So you have two choices: modify the velocity at some point along the way (and decide how you want to optimize that-- smallest adjustment? Earliest adjustment?), or accept that one time step will occur just before apogee and the next just after.

Comment: @Beta, if I understand correctly, you mean that there's no way it can **exactly** be V = 0; Y = TARGET. That's just fine! It doesn't need to be exactly that value, it be V = 0.00001 for example, that's ok.

Comment: @Veehmot look at this answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174961/2521214 it might help (it have all the computations you need I think) btw statement `y += (gravity / 2 + velocity);` is not correct (if you want the real thing)

Comment: @Spektre: `y += (gravity / 2 + velocity);` is correct when the calculations are being done at discreet intervals of one time-unit.

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate the correct initial velocity, you must know the *difference* between the target altitude and the initial altitude (i.e. how far up you want to go), not just the target. So you have three choices, you can pass both parameters to `hitTarget`, you can set the initial y as a constant available to `hitTarget`, or you can pass one parameter, the difference (i.e. y<sub>final</sub>-y<sub>initial</sub>). I'll do it the third way; converting to one of the other two is trivial.

```
function hitTarget(y) {
  velocity = -sqrt(-2 * g * y);  // remember that y<=0 (or there's no solution)
}
```