# An arc in javascript

Tags: javascript, physics, createjs

Hi I've been looking at cannonball physics and how to implement them in a game.

I'd like to apply gravity to the cannonball and x and y velocity relative to the mouse
cursor position. So that the cannonball travels toward your mouse position.

Further away the mouse cursor (from the cannon) the higher the velocity.

The angle should match the position of the cursor on the canvas.

I've hunted this out for quite a few days now, so now I'm asking.

Who knows of a nice cannonball physics using javascript and canvas?

```
    units = 10,
pixelsPerMeter = stage.width / units,
startlaunch = Math.PI/4,
launchAngle = startlaunch;

bang = {
    lastTime: 0,
    gravity: 9.81,

    applyGravity: function (elapsed) {
        bullet1.velocityY = (this.gravity * elapsed) -
                            (launchVelocity * Math.sin(launchAngle));
    },

    updateBulletPosition: function (updateDelta) {

        bullet1.left += bullet1.velocityX * (updateDelta) * pixelsPerMeter;
        bullet1.top += bullet1.velocityY * (updateDelta) * pixelsPerMeter;
    },

    execute: function (bullet1, time) {
        var updateDelta,
            elapsedFlightTime;
            if(bulletInFlight){
                elapsedFrameTime = (time - this.lastTime)/1000;
                elapsedFlightTime = (time - launchTime)/1000;

                this.applyGravity(elapsedFlightTime);
                this.updateBulletPosition(elapsedFrameTime);
            }
            this.lastTime = time;
    }
}


cannon.rotation = cannon.on("tick", function(event) {
    var angle = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - cannon.y, stage.mouseX - cannon.x );
    angle = angle * (180/Math.PI);
     // The following if statement is optional and converts our angle from being
    // -180 to +180 degrees to 0-360 degrees.  It is completely optional
    if(angle < 0){
        angle = 360 - (-angle);}
    // Atan2 results have 0 degrees point down the positive X axis, while our image is pointed up.
    // Therefore we simply add 90 degrees to the rotation to orient our image
    // If 0 degrees is to the right on your image, you do not need to add 90
    cannon.rotation = 90 + angle;
     });

var fire = false, gravity = 6, vy = 3, vx = 3;

oneback.on("click", function(e) {

        bullet1.x = cannon.x;
        bullet1.y = cannon.y;
        scene1.addChild(bullet1);
        fire = true;

//e.preventDefault();

bullet1.rotation = cannon.rotation;

if(fire == false){
    bullet1.vx = Math.cos(bullet1.x-stage.mouseX) * this.vx;// used to be... this.bullet_speed'.
    bullet1.vy = Math.sin(bullet1.y-stage.mouseY) * this.vy;
}
});

oneback.on("click", function(e){

e.preventDefault();

if(fire == true) {
    loc = (stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
    lastMouse.left = loc.x;
    lastMouse.top = loc.y;

    deltaX = Math.abs(lastMouse.left - bullet1.left);
    deltaY = Math.abs(lastMouse.top - bullet1.top);

    launchAngle = Math.atan(parseFloat(deltaY) / parseFloat (deltaX));
    launchVelocity = 4 * deltaY / Math.sin (launchAngle) / pixelsPerMeter;
 }
 });



bullet1.on("tick", function(event){
    if(fire == true){
        bullet1.y += vy - gravity;
        bullet1.x += vx - gravity;

        // bullet1.y -= stage.mouseY;
        //bullet1.x -= stage.mouseX;
        //bullet1.x = direction - gravity;
        //bullet1.y = direction - gravity;
        }


});
```

Comment: This search query provides a list of JavaScript physics engines: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript+physics+engine

Comment: @Harry 1. your title is misleading 2. your current question suggest tool/lib finding which is off topic here 3. if you want the physics look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174961/2521214 if gfx then specify closely (not JAVA programer byt isnt Canvas equivalent to Wndows GDI? so there should be spline,arc,ellipticarc...) what did you try?

Comment: Hi @Spektre, have added code sample, hopefully this explains my efforts somewhat better

Comment: @Harry and what is the problem exactly? it looks like you have it almost done. Also the formulation is weird didn't you want to drive cannon escape velocity and angle by mouse instead of angle and gravity (that would make more sense)? also apply gravity can be done inside `updateBulletPosition` just compute the velocity from accelerations in the same way as position

Comment: Thanks @Spektre, that makes more sense, I'll keep at it and when I've finished I'll post the final result. Might be useful to someone